# Reason: <class 'TypeError'> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, json

I want to write the content:

```
sample = {'Details': [{'user1': '{"d8": "X121", "d0": "NIL", "d4": false, "d3": false, "d2": false}', 'name': 'set a sample'}], 'person1': 1}
```

using code:

```py
s1 = json.dumps(sample).replace('"', '"').replace("'", "'")
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
ftp.putfo(BytesIO(s1), 'newfile.txt')
```

But getting error:

> Reason: <class 'TypeError'> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Edit 2:

```
import json
        per_json = {'d8': 'X121',
    'd0': 'NIL',
    'd4': False,
    'd3': False,
    'd2': False}
        p1 = {
            "name" : "set a sample"
        }

        p1["additional_info"] = json.dumps(per_json)
        p1_list={"person1":1}
        p1_list["Details"]=[p1]
        s1 = json.dumps(p1_list).replace('}"', "}").replace('"{', "{").replace('\\"', '"')
        ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
        ftp.putfo(s1, 'newfile.txt')
        ftp.close()
```

Reason: <class 'AttributeError'> 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: What do you intend with `.replace('"', '"')` and `.replace("'", "'")`?

Comment: Please include the whole traceback